# Firebase auth don't allow previous 10 passwords

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Does firebase auth allow you to prohibit using previous x passwords?  If so does anyone know who to configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Authentication doesn't have any configurations that enforce password rules like this.  The only limitations on use of the API are documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits).

If you want to implement rules like this, you would have to somehow store prior password yourself and compare them.  But generally speaking, it's a bad idea to store plaintext passwords in your database.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @doug-stevenson.  Love your firecast videos.  The cloud function cold start one was recently helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the previous answer, Firebase Auth does not currently support this.

What we have had to do in order to implement this is to have a separate flow for password reset, whereby we store the user's historical password choices in a separate Firebase document associated with the user.

As noted by the previous answer, you MUST NOT store those passwords in clear text. Instead, you store an appropriately hashed copy of the password. Then you hash the new password and compare its hash against the list of previous hashed password. If it matches one, you reject it. If it doesn't match, you proceed with using that password for the account and add the hash to the list of previous hashes.

Given the way you have asked this question, you are likely in a regulatory-sensitive environment. As such, I would recommend looking up the appropriate FIPS 140 recommended solution. For FIPS 140 sensitive environments, [OWASP](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet.html) guides you to use PBKDF2 with 600,000 iterations and further to apply a "pepper" via HMAC with SHA 256, where the secret/pepper is stored outside of Firebase.

Since you are using Firebase, I'm assuming you have access to the rest of Google Cloud. You can use Google Cloud Key Management to create a Key for purposes of HMAC signing and specify the appropriate HMAC algorithm (be sure to set the key purpose to "MAC" and not "ASYMMETRIC_SIGN", because you will be using the macSign/macVerify functions and not the asymmetricSign function). Further, when you create the key, you can specify the "protectionLevel" to be "HSM". This will get you to what FIPS 140/OWASP is recommending: PBKDF2 with an HMAC applied, externally stored ([using a FIPS 140-2 validated HSM](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/Certificate/3318), no less) secret.

It's a bit of work, and I really wish Firebase/Identity Platform would offer this out of the box because it's easy to get wrong.

Well, this and "check against known password corpus" (in the same password reset workflow, [query against HaveIBeenPwned's Pwned Password corpus](https://haveibeenpwned.com/Passwords)) and several other features that should be check boxes for a service like this.